# passing textfield value from another textfield in java

Tags: java, gwt

I have two textfields using gwt and I would like to pass the text that I have in my first textfield in to my second textfield

```
name = txtName.getText();
TextField txtName = new TextField();
txtName.setAllowBlank(false);
txtName.setEmptyText("c.gornez");
vlc.add(new FieldLabel(txtName, "Name"), new VerticalLayoutData(1, -1, new Margins(10)));
name = txtName.getText();

TextField txtMailbox = new TextField();
txtMailbox.setAllowBlank(false);
txtMailbox.setEmptyText("c.gornez");
vlc.add(new FieldLabel(txtMailbox, "Mailbox"), new VerticalLayoutData(1, -1, new Margins(10)));
mailbox = txtMailbox.getText();
```

Comment: Do you want to change txtMailBox value after each change of txtName value, after each key press in txtName or after a button click ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want change **txtMailBox** after each change of **txtName** value, you should add a **value change handler** to **txtName** (see code below).

```
txtName.addValueChangeHandler ( new ValueChangeHandler<String>() {
  @Override
  public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event) {
    final String name = event.getValue()
    txtMailBox.setText(name);
  }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
txtMailbox.setText(txtName.getText())
```